# The system is running in low-graphic mode

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

Horror in Halloween :-(
my ubuntu desktop has been working well. Yesterday, it ran out of juice and shutdown while I am doing some work.   Now it shows "The system is running in low-graphic mode" when I boot it up.  I can still ssh into this laptop from another PC but I am not able to directly use it (don't get the login screen).  My ubuntu is 14.04LTS

"lspci" command shows that it's Intel graphic card (kernel driver i915, I don't know intel graphic card model though). I have seen some similar questions to this one, but they are not using Intel Graphic card,so the solution does't seem to apply.

I suspect my graphic driver is at fault and tried to install the driver:

I found this page that potentially contains the driver:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7

However, the link given is wrong "Intel® Graphics Stack Release 2014Q3 for Linux".  I did some googling and found the correct link: 
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014q3-intel-graphics-stack-release

However,  there is a bunch of links in Download section. I guess they are some source code.

I really don't how to proceed to solve this problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear, when I have this problem, what I do first is to run a new installation to see if it is really a problem on your drivers or the graphic board went crazy.

I suggest you also to keep the latest versions, not having the latest updated may be safe, but can also cause you problems.

Comment: Thanks @user193385 for your quick reply.  I used Ubuntu CD and did a "try" on the laptop, it worked fine. Appears that my hardware is ok :-), still need to figure out how to get the driver stuff right.